# Creating Dynamodb table, 3 search columns apart from partition key, is it possible?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

[image: Dynamodb table]

Hi, I have created a dynamodb table but this has errors when i try to perform table.GetItem with only username (image attached)

Found this is poorly designed table, so thought of recreating a new table, my question is how to set attributes, local secondary index and global secondary index for a table with one primary key and 3 search columns.
or
Is it possible to have 3 more search columns(User_email, Username,Usertype) apart from partition key column(user_ID) in dynamodb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetItem API` requires both partition key and sort key. However, you can use `Query API` with only partition key attribute value. Sort key is not mandatory for Query API.

**Get Item Rule:-**

> For the primary key, you must provide all of the attributes. For
>   example, with a simple primary key, you only need to provide a value
>   for the partition key. For a composite primary key, you must provide
>   values for both the partition key and the sort key.

You can define a maximum of **5 local secondary indexes and 5 global secondary indexes per table**.

An LSI is attached to a specific partition key value, whereas a GSI spans all partition key values. Since items having the same partition key value share the same partition in DynamoDB, the "Local" Secondary Index only covers items that are stored together (on the same partition). Thus, the purpose of the LSI is to query items that have the same partition key value but different sort key values. For example, consider a DynamoDB table that tracks Orders for customers, where CustomerId is the partition key.

> With a local secondary index, there is a limit on item collection
>   sizes: For every distinct partition key value, the total sizes of all
>   table and index items cannot exceed 10 GB. This might constrain the
>   number of sort keys per partition key value.

Comment: Thanks much @notionquest, //An LSI is attached to a specific partition key value// This implies that LSI will be helpful only if table has same partition and different sort key value. Incase, If i have unique partition, LSI is not required, is it correct?

Comment: If you have only partition key, LSI is not required. I don't understand what you mean by unique partition?  You can think of LSI as an alternate sort key.